# Can I use my iPhone internationally?

Tags: internationalization

I have an Apple iPhone 4 (model A1349) with Virgin Mobile service.  It works fine in the US but Virgin told me that it won't work internationally (i.e., calling within other countries or calling US from abroad).

Is there anything that I can do with this phone or do I need a new phone and/or carrier?

Comment: If you have iPhone Model A1349, it is a CDMA phone, and I'd follow the answer @lukiffer gave, as this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone 4 came in two flavors: CDMA (Verizon, Virgin, etc.) and GSM (AT&T, T-Mobile, etc.).

The GSM phone will work, however it will incur international roaming charges. Your CDMA version on the other hand will not work in most countries outside of the US.

I would recommend upgrading to the 4S or 5 as changing carriers will not change the radio in your phone.

Answer (score -2):

If you purchased your iPhone 4 from Virgin, you can ask them to unlock your phone.  If you got your iPhone 4 from elsewhere, it's probably already unlocked.

Once your phone is unlocked, you can put another SIM card into it.  When I travel overseas, I usually get a SIM card for the country that I'm in, and share my new phone number with whoever is going to need to reach me.  When you do this, you'll need to comparison shop to determine which local carrier will best meet your needs.  Some costs to consider include:

- local calls
- calls back to the US
- data
- local texts
- texts to the US

The disadvantage of this plan is that calls to your US phone number won't connect to you.  You could get a Google Voice number and temporarily forward your calls to that number, which will allow you to get voicemail online.

If it's really important to you that people be able to reach you directly on US phone number while you're overseas, then you should talk with other carriers and determine what their rates are for overseas usage.  Don't forget to check the rates for calling within the country(ies) that you're visiting, receiving incoming calls, sending/receiving texts, and data usage.

I've found that the rate for overseas usage is too high for my tastes, but your mileage may vary.  I always get a local SIM when I travel overseas.